# How to import speech_v1 in requirements.txt for a Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm essentially using this as my Python code for a Google Cloud Function:
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize#speech-sync-recognize-python

I'm unable to properly import the `speech_v1` library in `requirements.txt` file.

I'm getting this error:

> `Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "pip_download_wheels had stderr output:\nERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-cloud-speech-v1==1.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: none)\nERROR: No matching distribution found for google-cloud-speech-v1==1.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))\n\nerror:`pip_download_wheels`returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "<error id>"}}`

Comment: Specify `google-cloud-speech` in requirements.txt.

Comment: This still gives me errors since speech_v1 would be undefined.

Comment: Show your code that generates the error. Are you guessing that speech_v1 would be undefined?

Answer (score 1):

In your `requirements.txt`, you should specify:

```
google-cloud-speech==1.3.2
```

where the name and version correspond to this release on PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-speech/1.3.2/

This allows you to do either of the following:

```
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud import speech_v1
```

Where `speech` is always the latest version, and `speech_v1` ensures you're always using V1 of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Try to [import](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-speech/) `google-cloud-speech==1.3.2` instead in your requirements.